# Angular 9 obtener el número de fila seleccionada usando Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular

Tengo el siguiente código Html en `Angular 9` el cual llamo a un `json` que me devuelve los valores en la tabla.

```
<form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th colspan="2">Opción</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let td of tiposDocumentos">
            <td>{{td.codigoDocumento}}</td>
            <td>{{td.nombreDocumento}}</td>
            <td class="td-columna_botonModificar"><input type="button" value="Modificar" class="btn_modificar"></td>
            <td class="td-columna_botonEliminar"><input type="button" value="Eliminar" class="btn_eliminar" (click)="eliminarFila()"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que quiero obtener el número de la fila seleccionada de mi tabla a través del botón eliminar que tiene el método **(click)="eliminarFila()"**.

Realize el siguiente código en mi archivo `component` lo siguiente

```
eliminarFila(){
  var fila = $(this).parent().parent().index();
  alert(fila);
}
```

Pero me arroja como resultado **"-1"** en cualquier fila que seleccione.
Nota: El jquery ya está instalado en mi proyecto Angular.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Necesito ayuda para resolver este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con angular es muy sencillo lograr esto. Solo necesitas agregar `let i=index` para obtener el índice actual del `*ngFor` de esta manera.

```html
 <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let td of tiposDocumentos; let i= index">
            <td>{{td.codigoDocumento}}</td>
            <td>{{td.nombreDocumento}}</td>
            <td class="td-columna_botonModificar"><input type="button" value="Modificar" class="btn_modificar"></td>
            <td class="td-columna_botonEliminar"><input type="button" value="Eliminar" class="btn_eliminar" (click)="eliminarFila(i)"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Después eliminas asi:

```js
eliminarFila(i){
  this.tiposDocumentos.splice(i, 1)
  alert(i);
}
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtkr4x).

### Aclaraciones

No es necesario el uso de `jquery` en angular ya que muchas funciones vienen de manera nativa. Un problema que puedes tener es que angular no se de cuenta de los cambios que realizas en el `DOM`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Angel me ayudó muchísimo.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo no usar jquery, si estás trabajando con angular deberías tener todas la herramientas que ofrece jquey, y sin la librería que pesa muchísimo.

Dicho esto, tu tabla debería tener un datasource que estuviera suscrito en tu componente, de tal forma que fuera un array y se cargase dinámicamente. Lo mejor si está empezando es que mires [este turoial](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) de material table el cual hace las tablas mucho más escalables y reactivas.

Comment: Por favor, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), así te das una idea de las normas de la comunidad para dar respuestas de calidad y evitar que sean eliminadas.